# EC2 Instance starts and stops after attaching volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I accidentally deleted the root volume and am trying to launch my instance. Upon creating a new volume I got an error saying: "Instance does not have a volume attached at root (/dev/sda1).

I attached a newly created volume to the instance with the volume id of /dev/sda1 and the instance successfully starts, is pending, and then stops, all with no system logs.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How did you "accidentally delete the root volume"? It would need to be detached before it can be deleted. Anyway, is there any reason you don't simply launch a new instance from an AMI? Is there something still attached to that instance that particularly wants you to keep it, rather than simply terminating the instance and launching a new one?

Comment: Very unfamiliar with AWS, I was trying to limit my usage as to not exceed the free tier usage. At this point I'm trying to salvage the data I had on the old instance, which had not been backed up. I have tried launching another t2.micro instance, detaching that instance's volume, and then attaching it to the aforementioned instance, but that resulted in a clean instance.

Comment: It might be better to launch a new instance, then attach your old EBS volume as a secondary drive. Then, copy the desired data to the boot volume on the new instance. This, of course, assumes you mostly need the data rather than the configuration (eg applications, frameworks).

Comment: The old EBS volume was deleted after I detached it and from my understanding, unrecoverable. Thanks for helping John, I appreciate it.